# Secure access only to controller in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I created a basic IdentityServer4 as per tutorials http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html.
This consists of APIserver, JSClient and ID4 Server.

OVerall all is good, now i am trying to go one step further, I want to create a basic controller in ID4Server called AuthorizedUserController that is restful, and that can only be accessed by Authorised user from JSClient.

I cannot find any examples on how to achieve this currently so hoping for some guidance.

Comment: I would go for a seperate API, check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645644/identity-server-4-and-web-api-for-user-management/48654219#48654219

Comment: Can you clarify? My api is separate to ID4 server

Comment: Do not make Ids4 restful, but split functionality. Leave Ids4 for authentication. Create a new API and put the basic controller there. Treat is as another resource (one that in this case has access to the IdentityModel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make IdentityServer include bearer token authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("bearer", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "you identityserver base url";
        options.ApiName = "identityserver_api";
    });
```

And then have an authorization policy that checks for the scheme and the client ID claim:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("JsClient", config =>
    {
        config.AddAuthenticationSchemes("bearer");
        config.RequireClaim("client_id", "my javascript client");
    });
});
```

And then add an authorize attribute to your controller that specifies this authorization policy:

```
[Authorize("JsClient")]
```

Comment: Funnily enough i discovered this by chance at same time i posted the question. About 80% same as mine.